# Trying to do frequency analysis of an accelerometer output

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, sensor

I am new to signal processing. I have a 3 axis MEMS accelerometer. I have read its output into $\mbox{Matlab}^{\tt TM}$.

My problem is that the signal I am trying to isolate has a frequency of about 0.2Hz, but in the frequency spectrum there are no peaks in this region, there are only peaks in the region <0.1Hz.

The ODR of the sensor is set to 12.5Hz. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code (maybe I'm scaling the frequency axis incorrectly).

This is the code I'm using:

```
%% Sort Data
X=RawData{1,1}
Y=RawData{1,2};
Z=RawData{1,3};
%% Remove DC aspect of signal
X_Mean=mean(X);
Y_Mean=mean(Y);
Z_Mean=mean(Z);
XData=X-X_Mean;
YData=Y-Y_Mean;
ZData=Z-Z_Mean;
%% Sort out time and frequency scales
Fs=12.5; %sampling frequency
Ts=1/Fs; %time period
dt=0:Ts:Ts*19718-Ts; %time duration
%% Create frequency axis for plotting of Fourier transform
nfft=length(XData); %time duration of signal;
nfft2=2^nextpow2(nfft); 
Nf=Fs*(0:nfft2-1)/nfft2
%% Do fourier transform
X_fft=fft(XData,nfft2);
Y_fft=fft(YData,nfft2);
Z_fft=fft(ZData,nfft2);
%% Plot Frequency spectrum
figure
plot(Nf,abs(X_fft));
title('Mag of Xfft vs freq');
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Everything looks OK in your code.  Is it possible for you to share some of the data?

Comment: First step in debugging: Try your code first with some test signal with known results. Try a few sine waves or superposition of sine waves and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest comparing the output of your code with known methods already implemented on MATLAB. You can use PERIODOGRAM to plot the periodogram of the signal and check whether there is an error in the code or in the acquisition.

The periodogram $pxx$ and the FFT $F$ are related as follows: $|F|^2=pxx$.

Make sure to check the documentation to use a rectangular window:

ref: https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html